# Reommended wire gauge for prototype boards?

Tags: wire

What gauge of solid wire is recommended for wiring on prototype boards?

Comment: Depends on what it is that you are prototyping.

Comment: @Nick, it probably depends more on the contacts in the protoboard, as a compromise between flimsy connections and wrecking the springiness.

Comment: Depends on if OP is asking about solderless breadboards or proto/strip/vero board. The latter have no contacts/springs to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

22 AWG works well. [Here is what I use](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1311?gclid=CMrb75KJvMsCFdgBgQodsVQEFg).

Answer (score 0):

You may also like to try jumper wires, such as
https://www.adafruit.com/product/153

They have a little advantage: you spend zero time on measuring how long wire you need, and you spend zero time on wire striping.

The disadvantage is that your breadboard might look a little messy.